# Python parse a binary document from xmlns and save locally

Tags: python, xml, request, binary, xml-namespaces

So I have a response from a request call like this:

```
resourceType": "Binary",
"id": "07a6483f-732b-461e-86b6-edb665c45510",
"contentType": "application/msword",
"content": "UEsDBBQA.......
```

And it is showing in my code as:

```
b'<Binary xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">\r\n   <id value="07a6483f-732b-461e-86b6-edb665c45510"></id>\r\n   <contentType value="application/msword"></contentType>\r\n   <content value="UEsDBBQ
```

I need to extract the content value and save as, in this case a word document.  I have tried solutions based on splitting, and using ElementTree but I cant seem to parse the content and save it as a word file.

Right now just doing this:

```
with open('/tmp/metadata.doc', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content
```

Results in a write of the whole piece, and Word opens like this:

[image]

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Given that `response.content` is a string variable, XML can be parsed using ElementTree:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree

# declare namespace
ns = {'ns': 'http://hl7.org/fhir'}
# parse XML
tree = etree.fromstring(response.content)
# find content element considering namespace
content_element = tree.find('.//ns:content', ns)
# extract attribute "value"
content = content_element.get('value')
# save content to file
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect most appreciated!